# In the Avengers universe, which male "good guys" have ever hit a female villain?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

By memory, I don't recall many instances where a male "good guy" hits a female "bad guy" throughout the Avengers universe. It's possible this is because the MCU villians have been mostly men. In fact, in *Avengers: Infinity War*, in Wakanda the women seem to go off and have their own little sub-battle.

I recall Thor fighting Hela in *Thor: Ragnarok*. I recall Hawkeye bashing something into Scarlett Witch's head in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*. Maybe Starlord hit Gamora in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (?). Maybe this is it?

***In the Avengers universe, which male "good guys" have ever hit a female villain?***

Comment: Would you be interested in the TV series (including Netflix)? Also, does the conflict in Civil War count at all?

Comment: Should be noted there are some characters first came as antagonists (in some level), later transformed into protagonists.. Ex: Winter Soldier, Loki. Just pointing out there are no static *good* guys**

Comment: Also how do you define hit, i know it seems stupid, but if iron man blasted a woman with his palm repulsers (don't know if it has happened just using an example) is that hitting? does shooting count?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'll be honest, i'm really not sure what the importance of gender is in this context, but I've recently done another run though of the films (but not TV shows) and while i was not watching it with this in mind (so i may have missed some) but from what i can tell, the below is reasonalbly accurate.

**If this is basic research for some form of gender studies paper, then obviously you should consider the times when female "good" characters have ever hit men. As any paper that only looks at one side of a situation is very very poorly written.**

And I'm only really counting humans, as there is no telling what gender certain alien races are...

- Iron Man: 0
- Iron Man 2: 0... its mostly machine on machine lots and lots of female on male though!
- The Incredible Hulk: does the hulk count or just banner? banner 0, Hulk actually seen, 0, but in all that damage probably a few
- Thor: 0, but a fair amount of female on male
- Captain America - The First Avenger: 0, a fair bit of female on male again
- The Avengers Assemble: 0, hawkeye does hit black widow a few times but he is under mind control so isn't a good guy at the time, this comes after his arrow blows a hole in the ship which in itself hurts a lot of people and that includes BW and Maria Hill, and hulk at least intends to attack BW after banner loses control not sure if he actually does or if it is the damage he's doing that knocks her to the ground. from this point theres a fair amount of female on male so i'll just leave it left unsaid and very obviously known
- Iron Man 3: Tony Stark does fight with a single female extremis agent, the one that regrew her arm and then was blown up in the gas explosion, and there are other (at least 1 female) extremis soldiers that fight with the suits in the final battle, but these are controlled by Jarvis, which as AI is NOT male or female. Rhody does shoot at a couple but they are not killed by him.
- Thor: The Dark World: 0
- Captain America: The Winter Soldier: Cap blows up three hydra helicarrriers and we see females in the hydra crew so i'm not sure if this counts?
- Guardians of the Galaxy: Starlord does have a minor fight with gamora early on xandar, this is mostly with tech, and rocket also zaps her at the end of that fight
- Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2: 0
- Avengers: Age of Ultron: Hawkeye does zap Scarlet Witch...
- Ant-Man: 0
- Doctor Strange: There is a baddie that is female, but i can't remember what injuries she sustains i think he is defeated by the Sorcerer Supreme
- Captain America - Civil War: Obviously there are several instances here, but its Good on Good, Scarlet Witch and Black Widow are both "hit" by male characters, although Black widow only seems to spar with Hawkeye, and is only actually hurt by Scarlett Witch... SC on the other hand is "sound arm pulse thing" by rody, is that hitting? its obviously causing pain.
- Spider-Man: Homecoming: 0
- Thor: Ragnarok: Thor does fight scuffle slightly with Valkrie, and obviously does have a few fights with Hela
- Black Panther: 0 all characters you see Black Panther take down are male to my recolection
- Avengers: Infinity War, there is a brief fight with the female baddie by Vison, by this point considerable as male, and then Cap also has a brief fight as well, after that only female on female, or female on male
- Ant-Man and the Wasp, ant Man does fight with Ghost on several occasions...

Now if we consider female hitting male... then all the above words would just about cover Black Widows hallway scene from Iron Man 2...

Comment: Wow! That’s amazing, thanks! It’s mostly just out of personal curiosity as to how the movies are evolving (not for a paper). It looks like there’s still an attitude of it being unacceptable to hit women, even if they’re the villain. It’s somewhat old school.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones, that's fine, as i said, they're might be others but not that come to mind, i just don't like seeing people publishing one sided papers, that's the only reason i mentioned it. I would say its probably more that female villains are less common, in the majority world view women need more reasoning behind doing evil things, so larger characters it's fine, they'll be back story, but those that don't have any back story then its easier to just use generic male bad guy extra number 1 through 40.

Comment: @BladeWraith I think it is a little more than too few female baddies. A lot of the male Avengers fulfill typical male hero cliches. Captain America is an anachronism raised with the idea "a boy should not hit a girl". Tony Stark is a chauvinist who treats most women quite sexist. Thor also seems to come from a male-warrior dominated background, also treating most females more like girls than like warriors. Most of them follow some form of gentleman code, where a man should hold open doors for women and not hit them in the face.

Comment: Star Lord also has a strong "protect the girl and look like a strong man"-complex. The Hulk probably doesn't care, although he also seems at times softer to women than to men. Vision should not care much, but the JARVIS-Part of him was created by Tony Stark and probably influenced by his ideas (men should protect women) and will probably also be softer to women than men. Spiderman is also a boy raised to treat gilrs nice and special...

Comment: @Falco: I agree completely, i was more referring to the lack of generic female bad guys which pads the female beating up male ratio quite considerably. there are certainly more male antagonists, and the gentleman's code is definitely a factor in being able to portray a female antagonist in the same way, but generally speaking male protagonist = male antagonist, Hela is the only exception to this rule, in the MCU, but Disney movies are the same... female hero, female villain, male hero, male villain, take a look at the Disney films, its almost always the same

Comment: @Falco: again, very true, although the hulk definitely cares about puppies!!!

Comment: Stepping outside of Marvel, the Wonder Woman film is also interesting in this regard.  WW uses superpowers to savagely beat WW1 German soldiers throughout the film, despite being (erroneously) convinced that they're under mind control, yet balks at harming "Doctor Poison", a woman responsible for countless innocents' deaths throughout the film.

Comment: @Liesmith, It could be viewed that way, but to me that would be bringing Gender into something that doesn't require it. I view (there is no real right way to think of it) that war is war, and it was male soldiers only on each side apart from her, and both sides commited terrible things in WW1, depicted or not. but later WW realises that ares is trying to manipulate her into killing doctor poison, to give in to chaos, evil and war, so not killing her was more of a middle finger to areas, then that she was a woman.

Comment: @BladeWraith I'm not saying that the character of WW was sparing Dr Poison because she was female, but rather that the screenwriters considered that that enemy was the first one to deserve any consideration or forgiveness, despite being vastly more dangerous than any other human WW faced throughout the entire film.  They chose the female enemy as the only one worth genuine sympathy.  Earlier, WW is happy when Steve shoots and kills a German soldier she has bound helplessly in her Lariat.

Comment: Didn't the Hulk hit black widow at least once? it's not a male hero vs female villain, but it's still male "hero" vs female. however, I'm not sure you can use the Hulk as a hero, specially given he'd be the only one to hit a woman, thus actually further pushing the whole "gentleman code" and how it doesn't apply to a mindless creature... some food for thought at least

Comment: @Liesmith, ah, that makes sense, crossed wires in understanding each i think. apologies.

Comment: @BrianH. good point, he definitely intends to, i'm not sure if he actually does though, i'll have to go back and watch the scene again, i thought (again memory could be faulty) he smashes his way through the carrier after her and the debris is what knocks her over...

Comment: @BladeWraith Personally, I see it as more of a history thing than a gender thing.  There is indeed a gender stereotype that men aren't supposed to hit women.  The interesting question I see is whether that history continues to propagate in the form of movies (these movies) or not.  Though to your comment that "war is war," a more telling comparison would be how often a hero chooses not to hit a women where they would have hit a man, but that instantly becomes a subjective topic.

Comment: @CortAmmon, indeed, verging on almost a philosophical one.